# Скролл до элемента

Tags: html, jquery, css

Как сделать так, чтобы срабатывало событие, когда элемент находится посередине экрана, как на этом сайте https://byjakt.com/contact/?

Answer (score 0):

Пример кода с одного моего старого проекта на jQuery.
По хорошему цифры лучше получать динамично при загрузке страницы
$('#input_area1').offset().position().top
И от него для условия делать +- отступы.
Важно! Условие < должно содержать больший отступ от элемента, т.к. scrollTop отсчитывает расстояние от верха станицы до верха экрана браузера.
Поэкспериментируйте со значениями на практике и поймете, почему так.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 700 && $(window).scrollTop() < 900) {
    $('#input_area1').focus();
  } else if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 900 && $(window).scrollTop() < 1100) {
    $('#input_area2').focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Ваше текстовое поле на некой высоте 1000 от верха страницы</p>
<input id="input_area1" type="text">
<p>Ваше текстовое поле на некой высоте 1400 от верха страницы</p>
<input id="input_area2" type="text">
```